# Pytezos: structuring call for FA2

Tags: rpc, fa2, python

Can you guys help me correctly structure a call to the update_operators in an FA2? I tried everything single combination I can think of, and it still doesn't work

It says the structure should be like this:

```
Typedef
$update_operators:
        [ $update_operators_item, … ]

$update_operators_item:
        { "add_operator": $add_operator } ||
        { "remove_operator": $remove_operator }

$remove_operator:
        {
          "owner": address,
          "operator": address,
          "token_id": nat
        }

$add_operator:
        {
          "owner": address,
          "operator": address,
          "token_id": nat
        }

$address:
        str  /* Base58 encoded tz or KT address */

$nat:
        int  /* Natural number */
```

This was my final attempt and I'm stuck:

```
add_op = token.update_operators({
    "update_operators_item" : {
        "add_operator": {
            "owner": 'tz1...',
            "operator": 'KT1...',
            "token_id": 0,     
        }
    },
})
```

Comment: I don't use pyTezos so I might not know the answer, but either way can you please explain "it still doesn't work". What does this mean? are you getting an error in your python IDE/texteditor? are you getting an RPC error? is the operation failing on-chain etc. Please update your question and add those details

Comment: `$update_operators` is an array ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Groxan pointed out, `update_operators` entrypoint expects a list:

```
add_op = token.update_operators([{
    "add_operator": {
        "owner": 'tz1...',
        "operator": 'KT1...',
        "token_id": 0,     
    }
}])
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked!